# PyODBC 17 cannot authenticate to on premises MSSQL 2019 server via ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL cluster from a docker container using an Ubuntu image via pyodbc with the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication method.

Form this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16 (and some other sources) I gathered that the connection string should look as follows:

```
UID=<DOMAIN>\<USER>;
PWD=<password>;
Server=<server.url>;
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
Database=<dbname>;
TrustServerCertificate=yes; # (or we would get a certificate error, must be fixed later)
Trusted_Connection=no; # else we can't pass UID/PWD
Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;
```

When I try to pass this string to `pyodbc.connect` I get the following error message:

```
[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

I am a bit at a loss what this should mean. I also tried to dig into with ODBC tracing but the output is essentially the same plus some unhelpful additional information.

Comment: Regarding SQL Authentication vs Windows auth, see this example from [this (section 5.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16#example-connection-strings): `The username/password is passed in the connection string. server=Server;database=Database;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;`

Comment: So are you actually using Azure Active Directory?

Comment: @Lama How would I find out about that? Is that a server setting? I am not administrating the server, only connecting to it.

Comment: I suggest speaking to your Network Administrator. As noted in that documentation you linked, `ActiveDirectoryPassword` is to *"Authenticate with an Azure Active Directory identity using a username and password."* It's *not* for Windows Authentication. If you are using a Windows Domain, you can't authenticate that way; you need to use a trusted connection.

Comment: @Lamu Thanks, your comment was spot on. We use a mix of Azure AD and Windows Domain in our network but the MSSQL server does only offer windows domain authentication. You saved me a ton of debugging time. If only the error message was more clear (like "authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword is not enabled on this server"), I would not have asked in the first place.

Comment: BTW, the admin told my that MSSQL 2019 on premise (the version we are using) does not support Azure AD authentication. That is only available with MSSQL 2022.

Comment: Correct, this is noted in the [Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#security) section of "What's new in SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Preview". (Note that 2022 isn't out yet, it's only in preview.)